# DB function to see if three values are zero

Tags: sql

I have a function that returns an `INT` value `-1`, `0`, or `1`. I would like to assert that all three function return values are zero, such as:

```
SELECT myFunc(a) + myFunc(b) + myFunc(c)
```

However, using the `+` operator could return `0` if one function returns `0` and one returns `-1` and the other `1`. Likewise, a function such as `LEAST` or `GREATEST` could return `0` if not all numbers are `0` as well. Is there an operator or function that I could use for this purpose? I was thinking about bitwise `OR`, but that only works on unsigned ints.

I suppose the long-handed form is:

```
SELECT myFunc(a)=0 AND myFunc(b)=0 AND myFunc(c)=0
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Please tag it.

Comment: None in particular -- I'm testing things out in Postgres, BigQuery, mysql, or sqlserver.

Comment: you can use a `case` statement with the condition you just added in your question: `case when  myFunc(a)=0 AND myFunc(b)=0 AND myFunc(c)=0 then true else false end as col`

Comment: Does `myFunc()` mutate anything, or is it designed in any way such that subsequent calls could return different values?

Comment: That "long-handed form" doesn't look too long to me.

Comment: The only math-y way I can think to do this is to take the absolute value of each return and do the `LEAST()` of those results to see if it's 0 or not. Honestly, I would just do this as a `case` expression though as it's more clear what the intent is for the next person that has to support this code (unless the math-y way of doing has some significant cost savings).

Comment: @esqew no mutation on the values.

Comment: @JNevill I suppose adding together all the `ABS` would work too, but yes I think the `=0` result is the cleanest. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The most mathy way to do this would be ....

SELECT abs(myFunc(a)) + abs(myFunc(b)) + abs(myFunc(c))